# How can I change the angle of a ConfigurableJoint via script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ConfigurableJoint for a pendulum, so it just rotates on one axis.

Just changing the position of the pendulum wouldn't work, because I cannot guess the exact position, since all valid positions are on an imaginary circle. I would be much easier to choose an angle for the pendulum.

How can I change the angle of the joint via script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the short answer is that you simply shouldn't.  If it's driven by physics, then once the physics engine kicks in (e.g. the first frame) you should try to drive it with code as little as possible.

The long answer is that you need to apply forces to move it into position, much like you would in real life.  If you want a pendulum to stay still pointing somewhere other than straight down, then in real life you'd have to hold it up with your hand.  Now, calculating all of the forces involved would be too complicated for an answer here, but if you're not worried about it happening instantly, then there's already a tried-and-true solution called a [PID Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).  The basic concept of a PID controller is that you look at the current position (provided by the object's Transform) and you look at the current angular velocity (provided by the object's Rigidbody) and from there you determine an incremental force to apply to get it to where you need it to go.  It should be pretty easy to get up and running in one axis, but will require some tuning to get the forces right.